# Array handling Custom Functions VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I am trying to convert some excel VBA custom functions into a VB.net COM addin i can handle most functions fine but it falls over when one of the inputs is a range rather than a single cell. I have added a basic function below which falls over when trying to interrogate the Marray(i,0) with an outside range

```
Function getAverage(ByVal arr As Object) As Double
    'local variables
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim avg As Double
    Dim sum As Double = 0
    Dim Marray As Array = CType(arr, excel.Range).Value2

    For i = 1 To UBound(Marray)
        sum = sum + Marray(i, 0)
    Next i
    avg = sum / UBound(Marray)
    Return avg
End Function
```

This may not be the best way to handle ranges and I would be interested in anyone with a better solution

Comment: Have you tried Marray(I,1)

Comment: No i hadn't i was relying on the system telling me the numbers in the array were
(1,0)=
(2,0)=
Thanks knew it was going to be simple

Comment: Because excel range are usually defined as (1 to n, 1 to n).  So maybe asking for 0 is outside the range of the array

Comment: @MatthewSwanson why are you showing VBA code? Are you trying to convert that function to VB.NET or what is the actual problem you're having? Is a `Range` type variable being passed as the `arr` parameter? How are you passing it?